# Show that there exists $0 \neq v \in V$ such that $\alpha (v) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in R.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $R \subseteq V^{\ast}$ be such that $\text {span}\ R \subsetneq V^{\ast}.$ Then there exists $0 \neq v \in V$ such that $\alpha (v) = 0$ for all $\alpha \in R.$

Contrapositively, I have to show the following $:$

> If for any $0 \neq v \in V$ there exists $\alpha_{v} \in R$ (depending upon $v$) such that $\alpha_{v} (v) \neq 0$ then $\text {span}\ R = V^{\ast}.$

$\textbf {Guess} :$ Let $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n \}$ be a basis of $V$ then $\left \{\alpha_{v_1}, \cdots, \alpha_{v_n} \right \}$ is a basis of $V^{\ast}$ contained in $R.$

But I can't prove it. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with a basis of $R$, and extend it to $V^*$. Notice that since $V$ is finite-dimensional, this basis of $V^*$ must be the dual to some basis of $V$. Can we find a non-zero $V$ that satisfies the given condition?

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Assume $\text {span}\ R \subsetneq V^{\ast}.$ Let $\{f_1, \cdots, f_m \}$ be a basis for $\text {span}\ R$ contained in $R$ (this is possible since basis is the minimal spanning set and hence any spanning set should contain a basis). Extend it to a basis $\{f_1, \cdots, f_m, f_{m+1}, \cdots, f_n \}.$ Since $V$ is finite dimensional $V \simeq V^{\ast}.$ Let $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n \}$ be the corresponding basis of $V$ w.r.t. the underlying isomorphism. Then for all $i,j$ we have $f_i (v_j) = \delta_{ij},$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker's delta.

Comment: Then for all $1 \leq i \leq m$ and for all $m + 1 \leq j \leq n$ we have $f_i (v_j) = 0.$ Thus for all $\alpha \in \text {span}\  R$ we have $\alpha (v_j) = 0$ for all $m + 1 \leq j \leq n.$ In particular for all $\alpha \in R$ we have $\alpha (v_j) = 0$ for all $m + 1 \leq j \leq n.$ That's exactly what is needed to be shown. Thanks for your hint.